# Request clarity on TransformerFactory's XSLT Transformer in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

The Transformer documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer-javax.xml.transform.Source- ) says

> Care must be taken not to use this Transformer in multiple Threads running concurrently.

- When I used the same Transformer Object in a multithreaded environment, what could happen?
- Why can't we use the same Transformer Object with 2 threads ?

Can I cache the Transformer object if my XSLT source is fixed, so that all of my requests will use the same Transformer instead of re-creating it on each request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JAXP classes like Transformer are interfaces, and they have multiple implementations (the two most widely used these days are Xalan and Saxon). The actual effect of breaking the multi-threading rules will depend on which processor you are using; but in both cases they will be pretty unpredictable. The Transformer is likely to hold the current state of variables and dynamic execution context so you really don't want two transformations writing over each other's variables.

To avoid the cost of recompiling the stylesheet for each use, you need to cache the Templates object, not the Transformer object. In theory you can serially reuse the Transformer to do multiple transformations in series within a single thread, but there's no point: just create a new Transformer (from the cached Templates) for each new transformation.

Another thing to be aware of is that DOM isn't thread-safe, even in read-only mode. Don't allow two transformations to access the same DOM tree concurrently. If you do need to share a source document between multiple transformations, the best way of doing it ends up depending on whether you are using Xalan or Saxon.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This really helps a lot. One more question, when we use the Transformer directly with different XSLT, it is consuming too much of java metaspace and that metaspaceInUse is continuously increasing ? is it expected behaviour   ? what is the reason behind it ?

Comment: You need to raise that as a separate question, giving full information about the XSLT processor you are using, the stylesheet you are running, and the measurements you are making.

Comment: I raised a separate question at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091381/increase-in-metaspace-with-transformerfactorys-xslt-transformer

Answer (score 1):

To compile and cache your fixed code use `newTemplates` to create a `Templates` object, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTemplates-javax.xml.transform.Source-, then for each execution in a multi-threaded environment use `newTransformer` on the `Templates` object to create a new `Transformer`.