# Increase in Metaspace with TransformerFactory's XSLT Transformer

Tags: java, java-8, xslt-1.0, xalan, metaspace

When I run the following code with multiple different requests, the java metaspace is getting increased.

```
        public String applyXsltOnXml(String xmlString, String xsltInput) throws TransformerException {
         String result = null;
         try (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
                 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
             TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltInput)));
             transformer.transform(new StreamSource(stringReader), new StreamResult(writer));
             result = writer.toString();
         } 
         return result;
     }
```

Could you please explain what is happening behind the scenes ? why the java metaspace is getting increased ?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? What is the stylesheet doing? I don't fully understand how Java uses Metaspace but I would suspect that it is related to dynamic bytecode generation. You will need an expert on the particular XSLT processor to answer this one.

Comment: All classes I am using from javax.xml.transform.*,  I do not have any custom configurations, all are default.

Comment: In that case you're probably using the version of Xalan that ships with the JDK: an old product about which I know very little. If you were using Saxon (which implements XSLT 3.0 rather than 1.0) then I would be able to help you.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I have added the tag of Xalan to reach to the experts in Xalan.

Answer (score 0):

Xalan generates bytecode and I imagine that's what's occupying the metaspace.